# .htaccess redirect to https except admin url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cloudflare

I would like to redirect all frontend requests to secured site https and all admin / backend urls should remain unsecured http.
In addition, I use Cloudflare CDN.

My rewrite rules do not work, all queries go to https.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Please help me.

Comment: Use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work fine as you have it, although I would change:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin
```

to perhaps:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
```

If that is suitable for your URLs, or:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
```

(in case a front-end URL should have 'admin' in it somewhere)

But anyway, you probably just have a redirect cached in your browser from before you got it working. Clear you cache or "forget this site".

Also remove line two, no need to check twice.

But it's a shame not to run your admin over HTTPS too, just for security when logging in to it etc. and transferring confidential data.

**Update**

Since clearing the cache did not fix it (see comments) recommended [enabling logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging).

**Update 2**

Based on discussion in comments, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php)?/admin(/|$)
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This is because it looks like your application may be adding /index.php when it generates admin URLs. So this would cover that too.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, the second line for Cloudflare CDN, otherwise I get error toomany redirections.

Comment: Was it the caching in your browser?

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work? Please tell me exactly what is happening?

Comment: It redirects the example.com/admin to https.

Comment: Could you try a different browser just to be sure? Is there any other redirect logic set up anywhere? The next step is to enable mod rewrite logging and see what is happening, if you can.

Comment: It is good suggestions about logging, how I can enable it and where is the log?

Comment: [Info on logging here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging). The logging will be to the error log.

Comment: Maybe I misleaded you about the example.com/admin actually I write example.com/admin/user and ahter that the server goes to example.com/index.php/admin/user/sessionkey maybe becase of the scenario it redirects me to the https?

Comment: Well spotted. Then that's clearly some other redirect logic as I suggested. The rule we have here couldn't possibly be responsible for that. Have a look around for other redirects. The one here is fine.

Comment: I tried a htaccess tester here htaccess.madewithlove.be and the rules are working there, but on the server it doesn't

Comment: I think perhaps it can be solved by also avoiding redirecting `/index.php/admin`. I will update my answer.

Comment: I updated my answer and included an explanation there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort

Comment: Let me know if it helps. I'm not sure it will, since what you had before looking for `admin` anywhere in the URL should have worked too for this. So perhaps there are still some other redirects to look at.

Comment: Actually, it does not work, it does not work. I use Magento and it has its own rewrites.

Comment: Can't you just run the admin through https too? That would be the simplest solution, and better for security. Otherwise just post all of your redirects in a new question and be sure to tag as Magento and add as much info as possible.

Comment: Admin part of magento has many unsecure functions that blocked by browser during secured session. So I can't set all the server behind https

Comment: I'm sure Magento can be properly set up for https admin. How about the `Use secure URLs in admin` option. See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30758/how-to-enable-https-for-my-magento-site I suggest researching how to do this properly instead of finding a way round it. Here is a tutorial: https://www.siteground.co.uk/tutorials/magento/magento_ssl.htm