# Rewrite code htaccess stop work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Scenario

- Apache Apache/2.4.6 (Centos 7) ISPConfig 3
- Magento 1.9
- Multishop

Before restore VPS code in htaccess wor fine.

if user request a http://mydomain/any -> https://redirectdomain/any
But if request a  http://mydomain/adminpanel/  redirect it's not needs

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/adminpanel/$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.anotherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

[Full .htaccess](https://paste.tamainut.info/view/3d0f0afb)

But after restore all request go to https://www.anotherdomain.com/$1

A lot o test...

But this line not work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/adminpanel/$
```

[Debug Error lelevel 3 Apache mod_rwrite](http://paste.tamainut.info/view/032a33c6)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409604/htaccess-redirect-to-https-except-admin-url

Comment: I try this but not work. @wp78de. Put Apache with mod_rewrite log devel, but i don't understand the problem.. On all cases, all redirects send to https://www.anotherdomain.com/$1. Rule !/adminpanel/$ not work. Desesperate.